# Issue with ViewPagerIndicator in Android when orientation is changed

Tags: android, android-orientation, orientation-changes, viewpagerindicator

I have implemented the [Jake Wharton's](https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator) ViewPagerIndicator. Here, I am reloading the data when the orientation is changed.

In landscape I have 6 pages & I have scrolled to last page. The result is here
[image: here]

Now, I have changed the orientation to portrait. Now portrait has only 4 pages. But, the result is here.

[image]

Here the indicator has gone out of the available items.

But, the selected page is 1.

How to resolve this issue?
I have used the following line

`circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(0);`

Even then its not working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have `android:configChanges="orientation"` in your manifest which is preventing the activity from restarting on orientation changes. Because of this, certain fundamental aspects of the view are changing (e.g., the width) and the control isn't updating properly since you prevent recreation.

Comment: Jake Wharton.. One more problem. I want to use this ViewPageIndicator in a sub Layout. This is GridView. I have another view called ThumbView. I want to switch between these views. How to do this? If I switch back to this view, then data is not getting loaded in this ViewPageIndicator. Please help me!!

Answer (score 0):

circlePageIndicator.setCurrentItem(0); selects page at position 1?